# Recording my Windows machine in widescreen

Tags: windows, mac, display, recording, widescreen

I've recently switched to a Mac and I'm LOVING it so far. My setup is that I have a 19" HDTV for my Mac monitor, and a 19" non-widescreen monitor for my Windows. I also have my microphone (used for Skype) plugged into my Mac.

My issue is that as well as recording HTML and CSS tutorials on my Mac machine (or that's what I plan), I also have a series of tutorials on the UDK (which is Windows only and must be recorded on my Windows machine). The thing is that when I want to record a tutorial (I have to temporarily move the mic to the Windows machine); because the Windows machine now uses a non-widescreen monitor, I cannot record the videos in widescreen.

I NEED to record it in widescreen to show the full GUI and guide people around for my UDK tutorials, but my brand spanking new Mac looks horrible and is difficult to work on the small, non-widescreen monitor.

What solutions are there to resolve/soften this issue? I don't really want to buy anything extra since I just splashed out on a new Mac, but if it's necessary then I'll have to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that the only real solutions to this are:

a) Get a new monitor for my PC so it can record in higher resolution (hence HD).
b) Get a KVM Switch to switch the inputs to the main TV over when necessary

Hope this helps anyone having a similar problem in the future :)